# Jquery code produces undesirable result

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have an FAQ page, where I want the answer to the question to slide down from underneath the question.  I also want a plus sign to appear before the question is clicked, and a minus sign to appear when the answer is visible.  Unfortunately my jquery code changes the plus/minus sign on all the questions, not just the one clicked.  here's my code:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   $(this).children('.hidden').toggle('slow', function() {
       if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $('li p a').children('.plus').hide();
            $('li p a').children('.minus').show();
        } else {
            $('li p a').children('.plus').show();
            $('li p a').children('.minus').hide();
        }
   });
    return false;
 });
```

and a jsfiddle example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYZa3/)

Comment: Please edit the JsFiddle link.

Comment: done.  also, if there is a better way to write this code, please let me know.  I'm new to javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current selector `$('li p a')` searches the entire document for anchors which are children of an li which is a child of a paragraph. You need to ensure that you are only searching within the `.trigger` element.

See http://api.jquery.com/find/

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   var trigger = $(this); // Store the clicked object in a variable and convert to jQuery object
   trigger.children('.hidden').toggle('slow', function() {
       if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            trigger.find('.plus').hide(); // trigger.find() allows us to search using our CSS selector only within the trigger object.
            trigger.find('.minus').show();
        } else {
            trigger.find('.plus').show();
            trigger.find('.minus').hide();
        }
   });
    return false;
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NYZa3/1/

Can also be written like this:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   var trigger = $(this); // Store the clicked object in a variable and convert to jQuery object
   trigger.children('.hidden').toggle('slow', function() {
       trigger.find('.plus, .minus').toggle();
   });
   return false;
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NYZa3/4/

Or the entire thing can be chained (the `.plus` and `.minus` will toggle as soon as clicked instead of after show/hide animation is completed):

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   $(this)
   .children('.hidden')
   .toggle('slow')
   .siblings('p')
   .find('.plus, .minus')
   .toggle();
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NYZa3/5/

Comment: that works great.  I like the plus and minus changing immediately when clicked too.

Comment: PS:  extra props for the progressive enhancement in your example.  I'm new to this, and I want to understand the why behind it. Your answer was thoughtfully executed.

Answer (score 2):

You should determine witch "minus" and "plus" are children of.

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    var tis = $(this);
    tis.children('.hidden').toggle('slow', function() {
       if ($(this).is(':visible')) { // $(this) in "this" case is refer to the children!
            tis.find('.plus').hide();
            tis.find('.minus').show();
        } else {
            tis.find('.plus').show();
            tis.find('.minus').hide();
        }
   });
    return false;
 });
```

I know this code need to be more clear but it works know :-)
I Always encourage to cache the DOM object if you are going to use a lot in the JQuery action.
A very basic caching is to create a temp variable and put all the DOM (ex $(this)) inside so you can use it in every step of your action.

Comment: `if (tis.is(':visible')) {` should be `if ($(this).is(':visible')) {` .. other than that +1